# How to tell the date time that a git branch is pushed to remote?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

A developer may create a local branch for a certain time and and work on this local branch. After sometime, he pushes this local branch to remote.

How can we tell the date time that this branch got pushed to remote? This is for bitbucket, if ever that matters at all.

Comment: See if Bitbucket logs that information. If not, you can't find out, because Git itself doesn't store that information.